# How do I get hair particles to not intersect eachother?

Tags: particles

The picture shows it pretty good, I want to build a city by using a hair particle system. The only problem is, that the houses are overlapping eachother. I am already placing them on the vertices only (which would be fine if all houses were rectangular and aproximately the same size) but since the different buildings have different shapes, this doesn't fix the problem.

I am doing this in Blender 2.8. Are there any addons that can do this?

[image: Houses intercecting]

Comment: Do you ever tried grouping?

Comment: I feel slightly stupid. What is grouping?

Comment: Currently you have selected different objects in different Particles System and adding objects in place of `Path` seperately, right?

Comment: No, I have all the buildings in a seperate Collection which is placed by a single particle system.

Comment: I am not talking about the data you have arranged in Outliner Panel. Watch [this](https://youtu.be/gQUO9yL2vYQ?t=2382).